# Matlab figure callback move

Tags: matlab, callback

I am searching for a function that is notified when a MATLAB figure moves, i.e. when the figure changes its position.

In MATLAB since the beginning there was the callback which triggers when a figure has been "resized", but this doesn't help.

Any ideas or even solution?

Regards,
Domenico

Comment: Attach a [property listener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/event.proplistener.html) to the figure's `Position` property.

Comment: Good solution! The `addlistener` is available from R2008a onward. Is there something similar for R2007b existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the newer [`'SizeChangedFcn'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_d0e273293) callback or the no-longer-recommended [`'ResizeFcn'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_d0e273470) callback appear to respond to *movements* of the figure, only *resizing*. One solution, [as suggested by excaza in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209576/matlab-figure-callback-move#comment75432705_44209576), is to create a [property listener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html), which ties a callback to a change in a given object property. For example:

```
hFigure = figure(...);  % Create a figure
hListener = addlistener(hFigure, 'Position', 'PostSet', @your_fcn);
```

And `your_fcn` will be a function you create which will perform whatever actions  you want taken when the figure is moved. This function should be [written to accept at least 2 arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html): a handle to the object invoking the callback and a structure of event data (often empty). For example:

```
function your_fcn(hSource, eventData)
   % Your code ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edited 06/08/2017

### Don't use my initial solution in the first two paragraphs. It doesn't work.

Don't bother to find a callback function regarding triggering by the move of your figure window. Try use this callback [`WindowButtonUpFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callbacks-programmed-response-to-user-action.html), which executes when you release the mouse button, after having pressed the mouse button in the figure.

The approach is then very straightforward. Simply implement a function in "WindowButtonUpFcn" windows callback that detects the change of first two elements in `Position` property in your figure.

### New approach

I tested myself. Like it's mentioned by @Domenico, my initial approach doesn't  work. So, I looked around and searched for a similar solution. I finally found it on this [post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks) from **undocumentedmatlab**.

Basically, you have to be able to access callbacks in Java control to trigger a proper event.

Consider the following implementation

```
a = figure;
pause(0.2) % Wait for the figure construction complete.
jFig = get(a, 'JavaFrame'); % get JavaFrame. You might see some warnings.
jWindow = jFig.fHG2Client.getWindow; % before 2011a it could be `jFig.fFigureClient.getWindow`. Sorry I cannot test. 
jbh = handle(jWindow,'CallbackProperties'); % Prevent memory leak
set(jbh,'ComponentMovedCallback',{@(~,~)(fprintf('Check\n'))});
```

After testing, it works on 2014b and up. I hope it's useful for someone.

Comment: If I understand you right, you just use the `WindowsButtonUpFcn` assuming that the user is moving the window with the mouse?

Comment: Yes. I believe this could be equivalent to `addlistener` if you are writing a GUI project in Matlab. But if you just wanna add a listener afterward, gnovice's approach is appropriate.

Comment: And of course, you would implement similar check in `KeyPressFcn` and `CreateFcn` for some other circumstances.

Comment: I tried your solution with the offered `WindowButtonUpFcn` and it doesn't work, neither in R2007b nor in R2016b (the ones I tried). The point is, that the callback isn't triggered when you click on the title bar when moving the figure. Did you have another solution in mind?

Comment: @Domenico I might find a solution that is working for earlier version.