# Matlab: post callback after any change to axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to execute a post callback function whenever the axes limits change, not just after a [zoom](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html) or [pan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pan.html) event? For example, if a [panInteraction](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.interaction.interactions.paninteraction.html) is performed or the end user calls `xlim`?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about what exactly (and perhaps why) you want to do? My creativity might be limited there

Comment: Put together a double x axis plot and I want to keep the tick labels lined up

Comment: OK, this sounds like you need something like `linkaxes` but which maintains the initial configuration rather than indeed aligning plots. Perhaps a suitable workaround is to scale one of the axes to meet the other?

Comment: I'm already using `linkaxes` but that's where the problem lays. I want the `xticklabels` to be different while keeping the `xticks` the same. Since I can't just define a functional relationship between the xticks and the xticklabels, I need to go in and edit whenever the xticks update

Comment: the [`addlistener`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) function could be interesting for you. it was also suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209576/matlab-figure-callback-move) question. I couln'd figure it out now on the spot but I can have a look on it later if it didn't work for you

Comment: `addlistener` does well enough that I'm not going to mess with in anymore. I did a listener on the xlim property, which would cause an issue if EU set xticks but works in all other cases. For some reason listening on xticks doesn't do anything